# F# Recursive function for adding even list elements

Tags: list, f#, sum

I have a problem, namely, I would like to turn the following code into a recursive function for adding even list elements, but unfortunately I do not know how much ...

```ml
let even = List.filter(fun x -> x%2=0)[1..100]
let sum = List.length even

printfn "Even: %A sum: %d " even sum
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pattern matching to check if the first element in your list is even,
and if so, to add it into accumulator list and call the same method on the rest of the list. In case the element is odd - just call the same method for the rest of the list without adding anything to accumulator. When list is empty - return the accumulator and you will have list of just even numbers.

```
  let rec getEven (input : int list) (acc: int list)  = 
    match input with
    | head :: tail when head % 2 = 0 -> (getEven tail (head :: acc))
    | head :: tail when head % 2 = 1 -> (getEven tail (acc))
    | _ -> acc

  let even = getEven [1..10] []
  let sum = List.sum even
```

Function above will produce:

```
val getEven : input:int list -> acc:int list -> int list
val even : int list = [10; 8; 6; 4; 2]
val sum : int = 30
```

P.S. to calculate sum of the elements, you should use `List.sum` instead of `List.length` that will return you the number of elements in list.
Also note, that you can calculate sum of even elements in getEven function, storing not the list of even elements, but their sum.